# item has value but in Uint8Array return 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary, hex

hi i have `Uint8Array` like this

```
var ar = new Uint8Array();
ar[0] = 'G';
ar[1] = 0x123;
```

the second index is a hexa decimal number and i want to check `ar[1]` is grater than zero or not so i write this code :

```
if(ar[1] > 0){
  console.log("OK");
}
else{
  console.log("NOP")
}
```

but if i write `console.log(ar[1])` i get 'undefined'. this is a simple [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zokosasoki/edit?js,console) that i created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the number of entries needs to be passed as an argument to the constructor.

```js
const ar = new Uint8Array(2);
ar[0] = 'G';
ar[1] = 0x123;

console.log(ar[1]);

if(ar[1] > 0){
  console.log("OK");
}
else{
  console.log("NOP")
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**EDIT:** Reading again the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) you can use the empty constructor `new Uint8Array(); // new in ES2017`. But there isn't any working example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`UintArray.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/from) or pass the number of elements to the constructor, then set the value of the index using bracket notation

```js
var ar = Uint8Array.from(["G", 0x123]);

if (ar[1] > 0) {
  console.log("OK");
} else {
  console.log("NOP")
}
```